# MYSQL insert particular day of every month

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
id      |  due_at         | status
1       | 15 April 2021   | successful
1       | 14 May   2021   | successful
1       | 13 June  2021   | successful
```

How can i change the due_at column to be a fixed day for every month; Such that

```
id      |  due_at         | status
1       | 15 April 2021   | successful
1       | 15 May   2021   | successful
1       | 15 June  2021   | successful
```

I have tried this concept

`update tablename set due_at = now() + interval 1 month`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table 
SET due_at = CONCAT('15', SUBSTRING(due_at FROM 3));
```

Comment: This works but anyway to automate it such that I don't have to hardcode '15'

Comment: @manlike Send needed value as a parameter, or obtain in separate subquery from definite row's value.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it